# How to nest more than 2 levels of children routes in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, routes, angular5, router

I have this sample routes in angular 5. The 3 components are imported to this module. The component mark is generated under the folder of john component and james component is generated under the folder of mark component.

I want to load james component via path that looks like this: `https://my-website/john-route/mark-route/james-route` so I created this routes in the module file.

```
  const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'john-route',
    component: JohnComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'mark-route',
        component: MarkComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'james-route',
            component: JamesComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

But my problem is, it only loads up to mark component with this `[routerLink]="['mark-route']"`. 
And on james component with this `[routerLink]="['james-route']"`, it only shows correct path `https://my-website/john-route/mark-route/james-route` in the `URI` but doesn't load the component in the page. What is happening here, how to solve this issue or what is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your `MarkComponent` need also to have a `router-outlet` inside it.

To work with child routes, your parent component must have a markup part

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This lets your child routes to be placed in the parent component. The same must be done for all components which have children components.

For more see [**Routing & Navigation in Angular**](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Comment: can you show how it's done? I'm still newb in angular 5. thanks

Comment: I used this solution but I also need to replace the page. Not only by showing/adding `james component` but to totally replace `mark component` by `james component`. Do I need to have something like `*ngIf`?

Comment: if you want totally replace them, maybe you need them to be siblings, not a parent/child ?

Comment: oh. okay I got the idea. the `mark` path will be totally replaced by `james` then. thanks.